# Sorting a List of Tuples (Python)

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I am very new to Python and had a question regarding sorting of lists/tuples. I have a list of tuples (see code) and need to print three lists that are "city vs value". I've been able to organize the list using a specific key, but now how do I organize the list and then create a new list using only specific elements from each tuple? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

```
def getKey(item):
return item[0]

List = [('New York',54.9, 49.94, 2534.7),
('Los Angeles',65.4, 14.93, 3254.2),
('Chicago',49.8, 36.89, 2508.4),
('Houston',69.9, 49.77, 2577.9),
('Philadelphia',55.9, 41.53, 2498.4),
('Phoenix',75.0,  8.03, 3871.6),
('San Antonio',69.4, 32.27, 2629.2),
('San Diego',63.6, 10.34, 3054.6),
('Dallas',67.1, 37.57, 2849.7),
('San Jose',60.5, 15.82, 3061.7),
('Austin',69.3, 34.32, 2643.7)]

print sorted(List, key=getKey)
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the expected value?

Comment: @taesu I thought I was pretty clear (sorry!). I need to print three separate lists that are just the city names and ONE other value organized in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a new list with a *list comprehension*:

```
newlist = [(item[0], item[2]) for item in List]
```

replacing `List` by `sorted(List, key=getKey)` if you want the list to be sorted first.

---

By the way, you may want to store the values in a *namedtuple* instead of a plain tuple, so that it is more understandable:

```
from collections import namedtuple
City = namedtuple('City', 'name lat long elev') # or whatever your actual fields are

cities = [City('New York', 54.9, 49.94, 2534.7),
          City('Los Angeles',65.4, 14.93, 3254.2),
          ...
]
```

Then you can just do

```
sorted(cities, key=lambda item: item.name)
```

The benefit here of `namedtuple` is that you can name the elements of the tuple, instead of having to refer to them by index.

Answer (score 1):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> List = [
...     ('New York',54.9, 49.94, 2534.7),
...     ('Los Angeles',65.4, 14.93, 3254.2),
...     ('Chicago',49.8, 36.89, 2508.4),
...     ('Houston',69.9, 49.77, 2577.9),
...     ('Philadelphia',55.9, 41.53, 2498.4),
...     ('Phoenix',75.0,  8.03, 3871.6),
...     ('San Antonio',69.4, 32.27, 2629.2),
...     ('San Diego',63.6, 10.34, 3054.6),
...     ('Dallas',67.1, 37.57, 2849.7),
...     ('San Jose',60.5, 15.82, 3061.7),
...     ('Austin',69.3, 34.32, 2643.7)
... ]
>>> [(x[0], x[2]) for x in List]  # pick first, third element only.
[('New York', 49.94),
 ('Los Angeles', 14.93),
 ('Chicago', 36.89),
 ('Houston', 49.77),
 ('Philadelphia', 41.53),
 ('Phoenix', 8.03),
 ('San Antonio', 32.27),
 ('San Diego', 10.34),
 ('Dallas', 37.57),
 ('San Jose', 15.82),
 ('Austin', 34.32)]
```

Alternatvie using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> import operator
>>> pick = operator.itemgetter(0, 2)
>>> [pick(x) for x in List]
[('New York', 49.94),
 ('Los Angeles', 14.93),
 ('Chicago', 36.89),
 ('Houston', 49.77),
 ('Philadelphia', 41.53),
 ('Phoenix', 8.03),
 ('San Antonio', 32.27),
 ('San Diego', 10.34),
 ('Dallas', 37.57),
 ('San Jose', 15.82),
 ('Austin', 34.32)]
```